# Help choosing servo motor for Arduino crane

Tags: arduino-uno, servo

I'm building an automated Arduino crane where the base material is PVC pipes. The arm consists of the picking mechanism and other sensors, so the total arm might come to about 2-3 Kg (I haven't built it yet).

Can you please suggest to me an appropriate make/model of servo motor which I can purchase (preferably from India only)?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on where you are placing the servo, how much peak load & at what kind if distance from the servo.

[These Corona servos](http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__10347__Corona_538MG_Digital_Metal_Gear_Servo_7_0kg_53g_0_13sec.html) are capable of lifting 2-3Kg at a distance of 2cm from the servo centre. (look at the torque entry on the specification sheet)

Comment: Thanks, I actually went ahead using a normal 10 RPM motor and stopped it when an object was detected. It is quite accurate